# How to list the most compute instances' info for a project in GCP?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-python

I am trying to list all VMs that exist under all projects associated with my account, **including their OS** and any other tag I can find. I have a list with the projects already so what I am using is:

```
 for project in project_df["project_id"]:
    subprocess.run(["gcloud config set project {}".format(project)], shell=True)
    cp = subprocess.run(["gcloud compute instances os-inventory list-instances"], shell=True)
    print(cp)
```

This does work, but the only labels I get are:

```
NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE PREEMPTIBLE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
```

How can I get the OS of the VMs? And possible more tags? I tried using:
GET [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/aggregated/instances](https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%7Bproject%7D/aggregated/instances), without success since I couldn't make `requests` or `urllib` work with it.

Is there any other python library from the sdk or another gcloud command that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @DazWilkin 's answer, what worked for my case was the following:

I ran `gcloud compute instances list --format=flattened` that showed me many (if not all) possible labels. Then I found the ones that don't appear when you run `gcloud compute instances list`, and ran the following to get what I wanted:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format="csv(name, zone, labels.compute_machine_type, canIpForward,  labels.os, creationTimestamp, status)" > compute_info.csv
```

This way I also avoided using the compute API.